# Mesos parameters for enabling communication over SSL with Zookeeper-3.5.7

Tags: ssl, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere

Recently, I've been working on securing communication between Mesos master and zookeeper by setting up SSL authentication.

I followed the steps as listed [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide#ZooKeeperSSLUserGuide-Client-ServerCommunication) to have client-server communication involving zookeeper over SSL.
For a sample zookeeper client, say `zookeeper CLI`, the following JVM flags are needed to be set to allow the zkCli to communicate over SSL with the zookeeper.

```
export CLIENT_JVMFLAGS="- Dzookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty 
-Dzookeeper.client.secure=true 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.location=/root/zookeeper/ssl/keyStore.jks 
-Dzookeeper.ssl.keyStore.password=xxxx   
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.location=/root/zookeeper/ssl/trustStore.jks  
-Dzookeeper.ssl.trustStore.password=xxxx"
```

My question arises regarding how to pass the above parameters when we want Mesos master to communicate with zookeeper over SSL.
Tried looking for some pointers [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/building/#mac-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-macos-10-12-sierra) and [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/master/) but could not find anything that would help in this case. Further, I tried passing these parameters as arguments inside `mesos-master.sh` as given below but it does not solve my problem.

```
# Start Mesos master 
$ ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

Would be great to get some advice on this as it's become a potential blocker for now.

Thank you,
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

It's described [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/ssl/#runtime-configuration)

To enable SSL add following lines to `/etc/default/mesos`

```
SSL_ENABLED=1
SSL_KEY_FILE=/etc/mesos/conf/ssl/key.pem
SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/mesos/conf/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_REQUIRE_CERT=false
```

Comment: Thanks!
will give this a try.